# Sum information from another table

Tags: r, sum, left-join

How do I sum information from another table. Example: The table Y has the sales value, which sums in the table X the values through the column "ID".

table X

```
Id <- c(1,25,30)
Product <- c("Shirt", "Pants", "Shorts")
X <- data.frame(Id, Product)
```

table Y

```
Id <- c(1,1,1,25,25,30,25,30)
sale_value <- c(250,250,250,300,300,150,300,150)
Y <- data.frame(Id,sale_value)
```

I need add a column in tabela X with name "Sale_total", summing the values from table Y (column "sale_values"), throug column "Id"

Comment: You can do it with `data.table` `setDT(X)[Y, Sale_total := sum(sale_value), on = .(Id), by = .EACHI]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` Y and then `merge` with `X` in base R:

```
merge(X, aggregate(sale_value ~ Id, Y, sum), by = 'Id')
```

The result:

```
  Id Product sale_value
1  1   Shirt        750
2 25   Pants        900
3 30  Shorts        300
```

Or a left join with `dplyr` from the `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
X %>% 
  left_join(Y %>% 
              group_by(Id) %>% 
              summarise(sale_total = sum(sale_value)),
            by = 'Id')
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to join, then aggregate. Here's a way with `data.table`:

```
library( data.table )
setDT( X )
setDT( Y )
```

Join on `Id`, then sum values grouped by `Id`

```
X[Y, on = "Id"][ , sum( sale_value ), by = Id ]

   Id  V1
1:  1 750
2: 25 900
3: 30 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use `sqldf`:

```
X <- sqldf("SELECT X.Id, X.Product, sum(Y.sale_value)
       FROM X JOIN Y on X.Id = Y.Id
       GROUP BY X.Id, X.Product")
```