# Sum value between two tables with a condition

Tags: r, sum, left-join, conditional-statements

How do I sum information from another table with a condition. Example: The table Y has the sales value, i need sum in the table X the values through the column `ID`, when month is `jan`.

table X

```
Id <- c(1,25,30)
Product <- c("Shirt", "Pants", "Shorts")
X <- data.frame(Id, Product)
```

table Y

```
Id <- c(1,1,1,25,25,30,25,30)
sale_value <- c(250,650,250,300,300,150,300,150)
month <- c("jan","jan","feb","jan","jan","jan","jan","feb")
Y <- data.frame(Id,sale_value, month)
```

I need add a column in tabel `X` with name `Sale_total`, summing the values from table `Y` (column `sale_values`), throug column `Id`. Only when a column `month` is `jan`.

Comment: This is almost identical to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48581152/2204410). What did you try to adapt that answer? Did you try something like `merge(X, aggregate(sale_value ~ Id, Y[Y$month == 'jan',], sum), by = 'Id')`?

Comment: Try `merge(X, aggregate(sale_value ~ Id, subset(Y, month == 'jan'), sum), by = 'Id')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can add a condition to answers to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48581152/3768871). For `sqldf` case you can do it like the following:

```
X <- sqldf("SELECT X.Id, X.Product, sum(Y.sale_value)
       FROM X JOIN Y on X.Id = Y.Id
       WHERE Y.month = 'jan'
       GROUP BY X.Id, X.Product")
```

Condition of `WHERE Y.month = 'jan'` is added to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting my `dplyr` code from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48581270/3526832) with `filter`:

```
X %>% 
  left_join(Y %>% 
              filter(month == 'jan') %>% 
              group_by(Id) %>% 
              summarise(sale_total = sum(sale_value)),
            by = 'Id')
```

The result:

```
  Id Product sale_total
1  1   Shirt        900
2 25   Pants        900
3 30  Shorts        150
```